# Wireless keyboard HP Pavilion 600 doesn't work

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hp

I recently bought a new keyboard but I cannot find the drivers for Linux. I have found drivers for the HP Pavilion 800 model and the keyboard seems to work at first but noticed my mouse started acting weird (it acts as the CTRL key is pressed in). When I delete the drivers again my mouse acts normal again. Does someone know where I can find the right drivers?